# Quicker backup in windows azure

Tags: azure, backup

We are using windows azure for a software and when we release a new version of the system we usually takes the site down and we take a backup with the code below. (CREATE DATABASE databaseCopy AS COPY OF Database;)

The backup is taken to ensure that nothing goes wrong and that we can rollback to the latest version if we have created a bigger bug. However this takes a lot of time. (Hours) Is there a way to do a copy faster? We dont have any active users at the time for the release so maybe you can do it faster in another way? If not how do you usually do you usually do your database-upgrades?

Comment: It shouldn't take hours - how big is your database?

Comment: our database is around 10 gig at the moment. I guess it should not depend on how big your instance is? We are running this in a medium cloud service but the database should not be related to the size of the cloud service?

Comment: It is a slow process, not much you can do about it at the moment. We have a 25gb db and it takes about 3 hours. Word is that there are some improvements under way in this area, but no definite timescales as of yet. :(

Comment: thanks for your comments. I guess I have to live with these limits for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use SQL Database Import Export Service - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj650016.aspx

NOTE: There are many other ways as mentioned here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wats/archive/2013/03/04/different-ways-to-backup-your-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Comment: Problem with that is that it won't do a transactionally consistent backup as it an export. Hence Microsoft advice to do "copy database" first and then export  that. Of course, if the system is down then your are okay. However, using "copy database" mean you can roll back in seconds by just renaming databases, which is ideal in a deployment scenario.